# How to replace all special character into a string using C#

Tags: c#, regex

I would like to replace all special characters in a string with a `comma (,)`.

For Example:

```
Hello@Hello&Hello(Hello)
```

the output -

```
Hello,Hello,Hello,Hello,
```

(I don't known how to use regexp in C#)

Can i do this work using regexp in C#?

Comment: Define 'special character'.

Comment: What is your set of Special Characters to be replaced?

Comment: Make a class with anything you consider special. One to one - find `[special chars]` replace `,`  Many to one - find `[special chars]+` replace `,`

Comment: Its a good day to google `Regular Expressions` or from your Visual studio Help application lib. Microsoft uses the same regular expression engine for all of its langs (except JS, an abomination).

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Yes, you can use `regular expressions` in C#.

[`Using regular expressions with C#`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

string your_String = "Hello@Hello&Hello(Hello)";
string my_String =  Regex.Replace(your_String, @"[^0-9a-zA-Z]+", ",");
```

Comment: `Convert.ToString(your_String)` eh?

Comment: @tnw agree, why call `Convert.ToString(your_string)` when value is not null and you can directly call `your_string.ToString()`

Comment: Wrong. For example try input "Hello&Привет&Hi"

Answer (score 11):

Assume you want to replace symbols which are not digits or letters (and _ character as @Guffa correctly pointed):

```
string input = "Hello@Hello&Hello(Hello)";
string result = Regex.Replace(input, @"[^\w\d]", ",");
// Hello,Hello,Hello,Hello,
```

You can add another symbols which should not be replaced. E.g. if you want white space symbols to stay, then just add `\s` to pattern: `\[^\w\d\s]`

Comment: The `\w` doesn't match only letters, it also matches `_`.

Comment: @Guffa thanks, good note. If _ is considered as special character then `a-zA-Z` is more appropriate

Answer (score 8):

You can use a regular expresion to for example replace all non-alphanumeric characters with commas:

```
s = Regex.Replace(s, "[^0-9A-Za-z]+", ",");
```

Note: The `+` after the set will make it replace each group of non-alphanumeric characters with a comma. If you want to replace each character with a comma, just remove the `+`.

Comment: Why the downvote? If you don't explain what it is that you think is wrong, it can't improve the answer.

Comment: I can't see why the answer is downvoted as the other upvoted(also the accepted) answer says the same thing. But I can upvote an answer only once.

Comment: what if I want to allow hyphen? will this work 
s = Regex.Replace(s, "[^0-9A-Za-z-]+", ",");

Answer (score 4):

Also, It can be done with `LINQ`

```
var str = "Hello@Hello&Hello(Hello)";
var characters = str.Select(c => char.IsLetter(c) ? c : ',')).ToArray();             
var output = new string(characters);
Console.WriteLine(output);
```