# removing all special characters from string c#

Tags: c#, .net, string

I am searching for solution for some time that removes all special charachers is replace with "-".

Currently I am using replace() method.

for example like this to remove tab from string

```
str.Replace("\t","-");
```

Special characters:!@#$%^&*()}{|":?><[]\;'/.,~ and the rest

All I want is English alphabets, numbers[0-9], and "-"

Comment: At least you should define what is "special" characters exactly. Is it nonprintables or something else? And "I'm searching for solution" is not a good way to ask a question on Stack Overflow.

Comment: So, what is your question?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21388090/how-to-replace-all-special-character-into-a-string-using-c-sharp

Comment: As soon as you can define "special", the rest is fairly easy - you'll probably want to use a regex for it, as a simple way of expressing what you want to replace.

Comment: Regular Expression or Regex   google that

Comment: @AndyKorneyev all special characters other than numbers,alphabet

Comment: What about space? The £ sign? Accented letters? Numbers other than 0-9 (e.g. from different cultures)?

Comment: @JonSkeet all of them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Regex.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method for it.

Pattern for "other than numbers,alphabet" could look like `[^\w\d]` where `\w` stands for any word character, `\d` for any digit, `^` is negation and `[]` is character group.

See [Regex language description](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for reference.

Comment: @fali then include it into group. `[^\w\d-]`

Answer (score 2):

**Using regular expressions**

The following example searches for the mentioned characters  and replaces them with -

```
var pattern = new Regex("[:!@#$%^&*()}{|\":?><\[\]\\;'/.,~]");
pattern.Replace(myString, "-");
```

**Using linq aggregate**

```
char[] charsToReplace = new char[] { ':', '!', '@', '#', ... };
string replacedString = charsToReplace.Aggregate(stringToReplace, (ch1, ch2) => ch1.Replace(ch2, '-'));
```

Comment: I think I should go for regix that  allows certain input (alphabets,numbers,and "-") and disallow all the others. so there can be infinite number of other input so can't list them out

Answer (score 2):

LINQ version, if string is in UTF-8 (by default it is):

```
var newChars = myString.Select(ch => 
                             ((ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z') 
                                  || (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z') 
                                  || (ch >= '0' && ch <= '9') 
                                  || ch == '-') ? ch : '-')
                       .ToArray();

return new string(newChars);
```

Answer (score 1):

Removes everything except letters, numbers and replaces with "-"

```
string mystring = "abcdef@_#124"
mystring = Regex.Replace(mystring, "[^\\w\\.]", "-");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(function () {

    $("#Username").bind('paste', function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            //get the value of the input text
            var data = $('#Username').val();
            //replace the special characters to ''
            var dataFull = data.replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '');
            //set the new value of the input text without special characters
            $('#Username').val(dataFull);
        });

    });
});
```